# Converting unknown characters to Greek characters

Tags: c#, encoding

I have a file which contains the following characters:

ÇËÅÊÔÑÏÖÏÑÇÓÇ ÁÉÌÏÓÖÁÉÑÉÍÇÓ

I am trying to convert that to Greek words and the result should be:

ΗΛΕΚΤΡΟΦΟΡΗΣΗ ΑΙΜΟΣΦΑΙΡΙΝΗΣ

The file that the above value is stored in in Unicode format.

I am applying **all possible encodings** but no luck in the conversion.

```
private void Convert()
{
string textFilePhysicalPath = (@"C:\Users\Nec\Desktop\a.txt");
string contents = File.ReadAllText(textFilePhysicalPath);

List<string> sLines = new List<string>();
// For every encoding, get the property values.
EncodingInfo ei;
foreach (var ei in Encoding.GetEncodings())
{
    Encoding e = ei.GetEncoding();

    Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding(ei.Name);
    Encoding utfx = Encoding.Unicode;
    byte[] utfBytes = utfx.GetBytes(contents);
    byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utfx, iso, utfBytes);
    string msg = iso.GetString(isoBytes);

    string xx = (ei.Name + " " + msg);
    sLines.Add(xx);
}

using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Nec\Desktop\result.txt"))
{
    foreach (var line in sLines)
        file.WriteLine(line);
}
}
```

A website that converts it correctly is http://www.online-decoder.com/el 
but even when I use the `ISO-8859-1` to `ISO-8859-7` it still doesn't work in .NET.

Comment: Since unicode can handle all the characters in both strings in the same codepage, then I don't understand why they look the way they do. Has the first string been converted from an 8 bit codepage to Unicode using a wrong encoding?

Comment: @HansKilian I don't know if it has been converted from an 8-bit codepage

Comment: [See if this article helps](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17201/Detect-Encoding-for-In-and-Outgoing-Text)

Comment: Those aren't "unknown characters". This is ASCII text loaded using the wrong codepage. Use the *correct* codepage, or *don't* use ASCII. Store and load text as Unicode

Comment: And *YES ISO-8859-1 to ISO-8859-7* works! Αυτό μας έλειπε!

Comment: .NET Strings *are* Unicode. No transformation is needed. To read ASCII files that *doesn't* match your machine's locale just pass the `Encoding` parameter to [File.ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143369(v=vs.110).aspx). Using `ReadAllText` without the Encoding parameter defaults to UTF8. The StreamReader, StreamWriter behave the same

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the input. But I can't get it right. I have added the encoding  ISO-8859-1 in File.ReadAllText but no luck

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have added a like to the file which I'm trying to convert

Comment: Added how? Where is the code?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos added as a link at the bottom of the question. That's the file which I'm trying to convert. I wasn't able to do it using Hans's code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code converts the string from the C# which is UTF-16 to an 8-bit representation using the common ISO-8859-1 codepage. Then it converts it back to UTF-16 using the greek codepage windows-1253. The result is `ΗΛΕΚΤΡΟΦΟΡΗΣΗ ΑΙΜΟΣΦΑΙΡΙΝΗΣ` as you want.

```
string errorneousString = "ÇËÅÊÔÑÏÖÏÑÇÓÇ ÁÉÌÏÓÖÁÉÑÉÍÇÓ";
byte[] asIso88591Bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(errorneousString);
string asGreekString = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1253").GetString(asIso88591Bytes);
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
Console.WriteLine(asGreekString);
```

Edit: Since your file is encoded in an 8-bit format, you need to specify the codepage when reading it. Use this:

```
string fileContents = File.ReadAllText("189.dat", Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1253"));
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
Console.WriteLine(fileContents);
```

That reads the content as

> 'CS','C.S.F.  EXAMINATION','ΕΞΕΤΑΣΗ  Ε.Ν.Υ.' 'EH','Hb
>   ELECTROPHORESIS','ΗΛΕΚΤΡΟΦΟΡΗΣΗ ΑΙΜΟΣΦΑΙΡΙΝΗΣ' 'EP','PROTEIN
>   ELECTROPHORESIS','ΗΛΕΚΤΡΟΦΟΡΗΣΗ ΠΡΩΤΕΙΝΩΝ' 'FB','HAEMATOLOGY -
>   FBC','ΓΕΝΙΚΗ ΕΞΕΤΑΣΗ ΑΙΜΑΤΟΣ - FBC' 'FR','FREE TEXT', 'GT','GLUCOSE
>   TOLERANCE TEST','ΔΟΚΙΜΑΣΙΑ ΑΝΟΧΗΣ ΓΛΥΚΟΖΗΣ'
>   'MI','MICROBIOLOGY','ΜΙΚΡΟΒΙΟΛΟΓΙΑ' 'NO','NORMAL FORM','ΚΑΝΟΝΙΚΟ
>   ΔΕΛΤΙΟ' 'RE','RENAL CALCULUS','ΧΗΜΙΚΗ ΑΝΑΛΥΣΗ ΟΥΡΟΛΙΘΟΥ' 'SE','SEMEN
>   ANALYSIS','ΣΠΕΡΜΟΔΙΑΓΡΑΜΜΑ' 'SP','SPECIAL PATHOLOGY','SPECIAL
>   PATHOLOGY' 'ST','STOOL EXAMINATION
>   ','ΕΞΕΤΑΣΗ ΚΟΠΡΑΝΩΝ' 'SW','SEMEN WASH','SEMEN WASH'
>   'TH','THROMBOPHILIA PANEL','THROMBOPHILIA PANEL' 'UR','URINE
>   ANALYSIS','ΓΕΝΙΚΗ ΕΞΕΤΑΣΗ ΟΥΡΩΝ' 'WA','WATER CULTURE REPORT','ΑΝΑΛΥΣΗ
>   ΝΕΡΟΥ' 'WI','WIDAL ','ΑΝΟΣΟΒΙΟΛΟΓΙΑ'

Comment: Ah nice find, Hans ! with code ! you outrun me.. Above mess occurs quite often.. on old forums.. converted forums.. it is  what you get if you attempt to show UTF Greek from a database on a web page that uses charset=ISO-8859-1 which is simple ascii. Decoding it back..does that always work ? from clipboard ? Gonna try that code of yours, Thanks for posting !

Comment: @Goodies most certainly *NOT*. The Greek .NET user group is 14 years old and guess - no problems. No problems with databases either. It's *always* a developer bug - storing Greek as ASCII instead of Unicode.

Comment: @Goodies [Ο Sql Server ΔΕΝ ΧΡΕΙΑΖΕΤΑΙ κόλπα για να υποστηρίξει τα ελληνικά!](https://www.dotnetzone.gr/cs/blogs/pkanavos/archive/2007/01/18/23726.aspx)

Comment: It's a very common problem in countries with non-english alphabets. I'm danish and we only have 3 letters that aren't in the english alphabet, but they always lead to issues when people get sloppy with the codepages. Hopefully one day everything will be Unicode and *that* problem will go away :)

Comment: @HansKilian I have added a like to the file which I'm trying to convert

Comment: @HansKilian .NET and Windows *are* all-Unicode. We *didn't* have such problems in the last 20 years - devs that started in classic ASP (which *did* have such issues) switched to UTF8 as soon as possible. It's devs that think Unicode means `UxABCDE` that end up saving text as ASCII these days! Go figure ...

Comment: @HansKilian I tried to use your code to read the file which is at the end of the question but I wasn't able to get the right results.

Comment: That looks like an 8 bit encoding, so it's not Unicode. Try passing `Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1253")` to `File.ReadAllText`like Panagiotis suggested.

Comment: @alwaysVBNET I've updated my answer to show how you can read the file.

Comment: @HansKilian I do this: string fileContents = File.ReadAllText("189.dat", Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1253"));
Console.WriteLine(fileContents); but my output is: 'CS','C.S.F.  EXAMINATION','???????  ?.?.?.'
'EH','Hb ELECTROPHORESIS','????????????? ?????????????'
'EP','PROTEIN ELECTROPHORESIS','????????????? ?????????'

Comment: That's because your console doesn't support greek characters I think. Mine does the same. Try stepping through the code in the debugger. That shows the content correctly.

Comment: I've added a line that tells the console to handle Unicode correctly. So now it looks nice on the console too (at least on my machine)

Answer (score 3):

This is an ASCII file stored using the Greek (1253) codepage which was read using a different codepage.

[File.ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) tries to detect whether the file is UTF16 or  UTF8 by checking the BOM bytes and [falls back to UTF8 by default](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/file.cs#L783). UTF8 is essentially the 7-bit ANSI codepage for single-byte text, which means that trying to read a *non*Unicode, *non*ANSI file like this will result in garbled text.

To load a file using a specific encoding/codepage, just pass the encoding as the `Encoding` parametter, eg :

```
var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1253);
var text=File.ReadAllText(@"189.dat",enc);
```

Strings in .NET are Unicode, specifically UTF16. This means that `text` doesn't need any conversions. Its contents will be :

```
'CS','C.S.F.  EXAMINATION','ΕΞΕΤΑΣΗ  Ε.Ν.Υ.'
'EH','Hb ELECTROPHORESIS','ΗΛΕΚΤΡΟΦΟΡΗΣΗ ΑΙΜΟΣΦΑΙΡΙΝΗΣ'
'EP','PROTEIN ELECTROPHORESIS','ΗΛΕΚΤΡΟΦΟΡΗΣΗ ΠΡΩΤΕΙΝΩΝ'
'FB','HAEMATOLOGY - FBC','ΓΕΝΙΚΗ ΕΞΕΤΑΣΗ ΑΙΜΑΤΟΣ - FBC'
'FR','FREE TEXT',
'GT','GLUCOSE TOLERANCE TEST','ΔΟΚΙΜΑΣΙΑ ΑΝΟΧΗΣ ΓΛΥΚΟΖΗΣ'
'MI','MICROBIOLOGY','ΜΙΚΡΟΒΙΟΛΟΓΙΑ'
'NO','NORMAL FORM','ΚΑΝΟΝΙΚΟ ΔΕΛΤΙΟ'
'RE','RENAL CALCULUS','ΧΗΜΙΚΗ ΑΝΑΛΥΣΗ ΟΥΡΟΛΙΘΟΥ'
'SE','SEMEN ANALYSIS','ΣΠΕΡΜΟΔΙΑΓΡΑΜΜΑ'
'SP','SPECIAL PATHOLOGY','SPECIAL PATHOLOGY'
'ST','STOOL EXAMINATION                                 ','ΕΞΕΤΑΣΗ ΚΟΠΡΑΝΩΝ'
'SW','SEMEN WASH','SEMEN WASH'
'TH','THROMBOPHILIA PANEL','THROMBOPHILIA PANEL'
'UR','URINE ANALYSIS','ΓΕΝΙΚΗ ΕΞΕΤΑΣΗ ΟΥΡΩΝ'
'WA','WATER CULTURE REPORT','ΑΝΑΛΥΣΗ ΝΕΡΟΥ'
'WI','WIDAL ','ΑΝΟΣΟΒΙΟΛΟΓΙΑ'
```

UTF16 uses two bytes for every character. If a UTF16 file was opened in a hex browser, every other character would be a NUL (0x00). It's not UTF8 either - outside the 7-bit ANSI range each character uses two or more bytes that always have the high bit set. Instead of one garbled character there would be two at least.

File and stream methods that could be affected by encoding or culture in .NET always have an overload that accepts an Encoding or CultureInfo parameter.

**Console**

Writing the output to the Console *may display* in garbled text. The text isn't really converted, just displayed the wrong way.

While the console *can* display Unicode text it assumes that the system's codepage is used by default. In the past it couldn't even support UTF8 as a codepage - there was no such option in the settings. After all, the label for the system locale settings is `Language used for non-Unicode programs`.

The latest Windows 10 Insider releases offer UTF8 as the *system codepage* as a beta option.

To ensure Unicode text appears properly in the console one would have to set *its* encoding to UTF8, eg :

```
var text=File.ReadAllText(@"189.dat",enc);
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Comment: great explanation

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what codepage this is, but it seems to be simply offset by some values. You can convert the source string to the target string by adding 11 to the first byte and 16 to the second byte:

```
var input = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("ÇËÅÊÔÑÏÖÏÑÇÓÇ ÁÉÌÏÓÖÁÉÑÉÍÇÓ");

for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    if (input[i] == 32) continue;

    input[i++] += 11;
    input[i] += 16;
}

var output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(input);
```

Result: ΗΛΕΚΤΡΟΦΟΡΗΣΗ ΑΙΜΟΣΦΑΙΡΙΝΗΣ

Not sure if this is a solution, but it may give you a hint.

Comment: This works only through luck - `Default.GetBytes` converted this codepage string into bytes using *your machine's* codepage. Applying the offset converted it to a form that could be read as UTF8 only through luck. UTF8 uses *two* or more bytes for anything above the 7-bit range

Comment: I could use that luck elsewhere :P Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Just it c#

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
web.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(65001);
```